# == for multiple conditions at once

Tags: python, numpy

Say I have a np.array: my_array = [ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9., 10.]

So to check a single equals condition I can do `my_array == 1` and get an array of booleans.

Is there a way to extend this to check for multiple condition at once, something like `my_array == [1,2]` (which doesn't work). I want to avoid using AND as I'll be adding many such conditions which will change dynamically in a loop.

Is there an overall better way to approach this, maybe np.where?

To clarify: I wanted to find all elements in my_array for more than one equals condition at the same time.

Comment: " something like my_array == [1,2] (which doesn't work)" What did you want the result to be? What is the actual rule you are trying to implement? Obviously, none of the values in your array can be equal to the list `[1, 2]`, and also none of them can simultaneously be equal to 1 and equal to 2. Did you want to find values that are equal to *any of* the values in `[1, 2]`? Did you want to do *separate tests for each* and accumulate the results somehow? Something else?

Comment: What's the problem with using AND for multiple conditions?

Comment: a decent example would be nice here

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15939748/check-if-each-element-in-a-numpy-array-is-in-another-array answer your question?

Comment: Thanks Karl that worked perfectly. I was looking for any of the values in [1, 2].

Comment: Should I clarify the question since it wasn't clear or delete this as its stated elsewhere?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to clarify it if you can. If the other Q&A answers your question, you can accept it as a duplicate (which I just did for you, following your comment).

Answer (score -1):

I suppose it depends what you're trying to return, but you could try using np.where, for example:

```
array = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
sifted = np.where(array % 2)
```

Will return a numpy array of odd numbers.

Python's built in all() could be useful to you as well, depending on what you are doing with the output. The all() functions performs a conjunction across all members of a list on a given condition i.e.:

```
all(x % 2 for x in array)
```

This would return false in the above case.

Finally another useful thing to consider here are lambda functions and list comprehensions... By the sounds of it you are trying to do something flexible and dynamic, hence wanting the bools. You can use list comprehension to get the items you want directly, but this can get labour intensive if you're doing a lot of different things:

```
new_array = [x for x in array if x % 2]
```

A perhaps better alternative may be to specify lambda functions as and when you need them:

```
lam = lambda x : x % 2
print(lam(array))
```

This will return an array of the kind :

```
[1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0]
```

You can combine this with a filter to filter your results:

```
lam = lambda x : x % 2
filtered = list(filter(lam, array))
```

Comment: you are checking if the element modulo 2 is not 0 which is not  what the question asked. Question was to check if the elements are 1 or 2.

Comment: They're asking how to check multiple members of a list without using AND. They gave 1,2 as a trivial example.

Comment: Yes but I don't see how using the modulo operator solves the problem. In your case your resulting array is true for odd numbers and false for even numbers. How does this solve a problem where is the number is 1 or 2 returns true otherwise returns false?

Comment: You're focussing on the modulo operator, but the answer is suggesting different ways of testing conditions across numpy arrays. Using lambda and filters, all() and np.where(). The condiition itself is insigificant. You are misreading OPs question.

Comment: It looks like all the ways of testing conditions still just test one condition. The goal of the question is to "extend this to check for multiple condition at once".